# Show all data as default using sql / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a web page that shows data from two Database tables. The user can filter the results with three options which are. 'View by Region' , 'View by by Agent' and 'View all'. From what I have developed so far the 'View by Region' and 'View by by Agent' options (filters) are working but I can not get the the 'View all' option to work. I would also like the 'All' data to be shown by default when the page loads. I have used 'Dreamweaver' 'Server Behaviours' to build the code which I have tweaked with the basic knowledge I have.

**SQL/PHP**

```
$varAll_rsRTMs = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['property'])) {
$varAll_rsRTMs = $_GET['property'];
}
$varCounty_rsRTMs = "Berkshire";
if (isset($_GET['county'])) {
$varCounty_rsRTMs = $_GET['county'];
}
$varAgent_rsRTMs = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['agent'])) {
$varAgent_rsRTMs = $_GET['agent'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_Testing_server, $Testing_server);
$query_rsRTMs = sprintf("SELECT properties.property_id,properties.property_name, properties.address,
properties.town_city, properties.county, properties.`size`, properties.type, properties.acquisition, properties.image, properties.agent_id, properties.alt_tag, properties.title_tag,  agents.agent_id, agents.name, agents.url FROM properties INNER JOIN agents ON properties.agent_id = agents.agent_id WHERE (properties.property_id <> %s) AND (properties.county = %s OR agents.agent_id = %s) ORDER BY properties.acquisition ASC", GetSQLValueString($varAll_rsRTMs, "int"),GetSQLValueString($varCounty_rsRTMs, "text"),GetSQLValueString($varAgent_rsRTMs, "int"));
$rsRTMs = mysql_query($query_rsRTMs, $Testing_server) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsRTMs = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsRTMs);
$totalRows_rsRTMs = mysql_num_rows($rsRTMs);
```

*HTML*

```
<a href="right-to-manage-success.php?property=0">View All</a>
<a href="right-to-manage-success.php?county=<?php echo $row_rsCounty['county']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rsCounty['county']; ?></a>
<a href="right-to-manage-success.php?agent=<?php echo $row_rsAgents['agent_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rsAgents['name']; ?></a>
```

I have currently got a default value of "Berkshire" for the 'county' variable just so that something is shown when the page loads. But as I said ideally I would like all 'Properties' (data) to be shown as default.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: WHERE (properties.property_id <> %s) AND : try changing that to OR

Comment: Thanks @hungrykoala. But I tried that, and yes all data then shows as default but then the 'View by Region' and 'View by by Agent' filters stop working.

Comment: That's the problem if you have an all option it should have more priority than the view by region and agent, thus they will be neglected as it is already viewing everything in your DB, so my solution here is that if there is a value of either region or agent you need to execute a query for only those two, else you will perform a query for everything if the all parameter is set regardless if those two are set.

Comment: you'll have to excuse my ignorance to your reply @hungrykoala, but if I execute a query for region and agent alone. How do I perform the Show All value as well as All Data shown as default. Because I would need to bind the results to the page from the same query.. Wouldn't I? How else would I build the 'Show All' as default and Filter functions?